# Getting compile error when using union type in function parameter with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

According to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html, you should be able to use multiple types for a parameter in a function (see union part)

```
/* OK */
interface Moment {
    utcOffset(): number;
    utcOffset(b: number|string): Moment;
}
```

I am however having an issue with Angular reporting unresolved variable for the following method:

```
isFooBar(fooBar: Foo|Bar){
   if(fooBar.isFoo){ // error here
       console.log("is foo");
   }
}
```

I have two class definitions:

```
export class Foo {
  isFoo: boolean;
}

export class Bar {
  isBar: boolean;
}
```

Am I using it incorrectly?

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-union-type)

Comment: ok, why the downvote? Please leave a comment if there is a problem with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the parameter is a union you only have access to the common members of the two types. Since `isFoo` is not present on both it will not be accessible. For this use-case you can use an `in` type guard to check for the existence of the property.

```
export class Foo {
    isFoo: boolean;
}

export class Bar {
    isBar: boolean;
}

function isFooBar(fooBar: Foo | Bar) {
    if ('isFoo' in fooBar) {
        // fooBar is of type Foo here
        console.log("is foo " + fooBar.isFoo);
    } else {
        // fooBar is of type Bar here
        console.log("is bar " + fooBar.isBar);
    }
}
```